# Apostrophes not displaying under Mac OS

Tags: symbols

This is the MacOS's Texshop disappearing apostrophe problem.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

is added to the document preamble.

Within the program:

Preferences=>Source is set to UTF8.

Preferences=>Misc has pTex support unchecked (this solved the problem for many, but not for me.

Under

Edit=>Substitutions none are checked.

I have tried ' and ’ (prime and option-shift-right bracket) but the latter should always yield apostrophes but it doesn't.

MWE:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\KOMAoptions{headings=small}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}  %for strikeout text
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{idxlayout} %%to fix issues with index
\makeindex
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

    Apostrophes

Joe’s shoes are missing. 
So are Sam's.
The person's shoes.


\end{document}
```

Comment: "Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined (inputenc) in inputencoding `utf8'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this exact problem recently! I tried two things:

1. I added `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, with no success. I tried another, related package approach, but had no luck with that, either.
2. I manually replaced the offending apostrophes with ones I typed freshly. This worked. To make this more efficient, you might consider doing a find-and-replace. ***This worked!***

I also used XeLaTeX instead of LaTeX, for a related issue. It might be that if I had just used XeLaTeX from the beginning, I wouldn't have needed to manually fix all those apostrophes.

Lastly, the plural of *apostrophe* is *apostrophes*, **without** the apostrophe-s. ;)

Answer (score 7):

You need to tell `pdflatex` that the source is `utf8` as well.  Add

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

at the top of the preamble.

Comment: Unfortunately, loading this package or utf8x didn't work. Instead, the following error message was produced: "Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined (inputenc) in inputencoding `utf8'

Comment: I'm stumped then - are you using an odd keyboard definition?  The MWE you posted compiles without error at this end once I add the `inputenc` package as shown, and all the apostrophe's are visible.  But then I use MacVim to edit, so it might be something specific to Texshop.

Comment: Standard Mac OSX keyboard, no extra definitions. I think it's a Texshop problem as well.

Comment: Same behavior in Texworks, so it's not a problem restricted to Texshop.

Comment: As the comments show, none of the answers consistently resolve the problem which others have had. Manually retyping all the apostrophes in a 500+ page document is not really a solution.